# Pasar dato entre fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tengo una fragment el cual es una vista en la cual busca un usuario. Lo que hago es mostrar un Listview de 5 elementos, cada elemento es un usuario.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar un elemento de la lista. y dar clic en un botón (SELECCIONAR), me regrese al fragment anterior pero con el dato elegido plasmado en un EditText.

Ya hace todo, excepto que no setea el dato. Esto lo hago con el fin de no perder los datos ingresados en el fragment anterior al de buscar.

Código del Botón seleccionar

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) requireActivity().getSystemService(requireActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_excepciones, null);


            String nroSocio = txtNroUsuario.getText().toString().trim(); //Dato que se quiere pasar al fragment anterior

            if (!nroSocio.equals("")) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                Fragment buscarr = fm.findFragmentByTag("buscar");
                Fragment oldFragmentt = fm.findFragmentByTag("excepciones");

                if (buscarr.isAdded() && oldFragmentt.isHidden()) {//Si es fragmento buscar esta agregado y visible y el fragmento excepciones esta oculto entonces:
                    TextView tx = v.findViewById(R.id.edtAutoriza);
                    tx.setText(nroSocio);
                    ft.hide(buscarr).show(oldFragmentt);//Ocultamos el fragment buscar y mostramos el fragment expciones sin perder los datos que habia antes,
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha ocurrido un error en los fragments!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Seleccione un Usuario de la lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Espero haberme dado a entender lo que pretendo. Gracias.

Comment: Considera implementar el componente de Navegación, una nueva herramienta de Android para navegar entre fragmentos. Revisa en la documentación [Cómo pasar datos entre destinos](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data?hl=es-419).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar la información a tu Fragment usando un bundle, realizalo de esta forma:

```
  Fragment oldFragmentt = fm.findFragmentByTag("excepciones");
  
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("socio", nroSocio); //*valor a enviar.

  oldFragmentt.setArguments(bundle);
```

Dentro de `onCreateView()` de tu Fragment que enviaras la información puedes obtener el valor.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    String data = getArguments().getString("socio"); //*Información que se envió.
    ...
    ...
}
```